# Confusion with effect of averaging on standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

First of all, I was reading a text and stuck with this part:

[image]

Now regarding the above quote, I want to give two scenarios I made up to make my question clear:

**Scenario 1:**
Imagine we take N measurements from same sensor, and each measurement consists of 10 individual temperature readings (samples). And imagine each measurement has a standard deviation estimate of 0.5 degrees Celsius. (So we have in total 10×N data points from N measurements)

**Scenario 2:**
Now imagine we take one single measurements from the same sensor, and this single measurement consists of 10×N individual temperature readings (samples). (We now have again in total 10×N data points but from a single measurement)

My questions are:

**1-)** What scenario is the text talking about? What does it mean by measurements?(A measurement is a data point or an array of data points in the text?)

**2-)** After averaging, what happens standard deviation in both case(the Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 in my examples)?